# SQL: Select only one row of table with same value

Tags: sql, database, filtering

Im a bit new to sql and for my project I need to do some Database sorting and filtering:

Let's assume my database looks like this:

```
==========================================
|  id       |       email        | name
==========================================
|   1       |  123@test.com      | John
|   2       |  234@test.com      | Peter
|   3       |  234@test.com      | Steward
|   4       |  123@test.com      | Ethan
|   5       |  542@test.com      | Bob
|   6       |  123@test.com      | Patrick
==========================================
```

What should I do to only have the last column with the same email te be returned:

```
==========================================
|  id       |       email        | name
==========================================
|   3       |  234@test.com      | Steward
|   5       |  542@test.com      | Bob
|   6       |  123@test.com      | Patrick
==========================================
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what dbms is being used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Query:

```
    SELECT * FROM test.test1  WHERE id IN (
  SELECT MAX(id) FROM test.test1 GROUP BY email
);
```

[image: Your sample dataset]
[image: Query result]

Hope this solves your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a clearer way:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY email DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

A generic way to do this in SQL is to use the ANSI standard `row_number()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by email order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following query to get the `MAX` `id` value per `email`:

```
SELECT email, MAX(id)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY email
```

Using the above query as a derived table you can obtain the whole record:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
  SELECT email, MAX(id) AS id
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY email 
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```